# how can I write a function string replace (char a , char b, string s) that replace each occurrence of the character a in the string s by b

Tags: java

i tried in following steps. But I don't know what should I do next.Only use `s.equals(""),s.charAt(0),s.substring(1)`.Others way are NOT allowed.

```
public string remove1 (char c, string s){
string to_ret = "";
while(true){
   if (s.equals("")) return to_ret;
   char c2 = s.charAt(0);
   if (c2 = c) return to_ret+s.substring(1)
   to_ret = to _ret;
   s = s.substring(1);
}

remove("e","hello")
```

What can I do next?

Comment: You could use built-in replace functions. Or do you have to write your own?

Comment: what did you tried? your code attached to this question, is completely unrelated and not working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you can do this like following:

```
s = s.replace('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Except that the question states only equals(), charAt(), and substring() may be used. It seems obvious that it's a homework question.

Comment: From the title, it would seem the OP is **not** looking for the built-in `replace()`.

Comment: replace method is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

```
public String remove(char a, char b, String s) {
    String retString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char stringChar = s.charAt(i);
        if (stringChar == a) {
            retString = retString + b;
        } else {
            retString = retString + stringChar;
        }
    }
    return retString;
}
```

Comment: our tutor let me do this without s.length. Just those 3 methods I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you one recursion:

```
public String replace(char a, char b, String s) {
    if (s.equals("") return "";
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (stringChar == a) {
        return b+ replace(a,b,s.substring(1))
    } else {
        return ch+ replace(a,b,s.substring(1))
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework question?

```
public String remove1 (char c,char b, String s){
String to_ret = "";
int len = s.length();
for(int i =0 ; i< len ; i++){
    if (s.equals("")) return to_ret;
    char c2 = s.charAt(i);
    if (c2 == c) 
        to_ret = to_ret + b;
    else
        to_ret = to_ret + c2; 

}
return to_ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear someone is trying to teach you functional programming principles in Java. I'd question the choice of language for that. Even so, you should look toward recursion for your solution. Thing of the String as a list of characters.